# Using free wordpress themes HTML/CSS without php

Tags: wordpress, jsp

I have a java web application having JSP pages. I want to add wordpress theme HTML/CSS/JS to it.

I downloaded one of the free wordpress responsive themes but there was not a single HTML file. All files are php files and I cannot figure out how to add it to my JSP pages. I cannot use the theme as it is because it has PHP files and my tomcat server doesn't understand PHP.

Is there any alternative to get HTML, CSS and JS files without all php. I know we can view source the theme page and copy it directly. I just want to know if there is anyother way I can add the theme to my JSP pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that template download all you want to copy over is:

media-files, all images, css files & any js files.

then copy over the 3 main wordpress files that make up the template,

- header.php
- sidebar.php
- footer.php

copy all code from these 3 files into ONE blank document.
Delete all the wordpress method calls, and replace them with your file structure links

when your done you should be able to view your page in a browser and check for missing files etc..

Answer (score 1):

You have to strip out the HTML-parts from the .php files withing this template.
Also check the code within the .css in the template files you've downloaded, you perhaps have to adjust some images paths withing these .css files

Answer (score 0):

you can check it out the twitter bootstrap project or even HTML5 Boilerplates

1. [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
2. [Html5 Boilerplates](http://html5boilerplate.com/)